# Widget configuration inside theme

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

**Hi, everyone!**

I need to change my theme on the fly (for mobile version I have a different appearance), but widgets are not saving correctly.

I tried to configure widgets from the theme, but this method doesn't work:

```
if (!function_exists('sync_widgets_config')):
    function sync_widgets_config() {
        static $validConf = [
            'orphaned_widgets_1' => [
                0 => 'search-2',
                1 => 'recent-posts-2',
                2 => 'recent-comments-2',
                3 => 'archives-2',
                4 => 'categories-2',
                5 => 'meta-2',
            ],
            'wp_inactive_widgets' => [0 => 'gin-content-categories-2',],
            'sliding_sidebar' => [
                0 => 'gin-login-form-3',
                1 => 'gin-account-cabinet-2',
                2 => 'gin-content-top-menu-2',
            ],
            'header_area' => [0 => 'gin-top-area-2',],
            'pre_content' => [0 => 'gin-content-news-slider-2',],
            'global_menu' => [0 => 'gin-content-categories-3'],
            'footer' => [0 => 'gin-footer_widget-2',],
            'global_footer' => [0 => 'gin-siteheart_widget-2',],
        ];

        if ($validConf == wp_get_sidebars_widgets()) {
            return;
        }

        wp_set_sidebars_widgets($validConf);
    }

    sync_widgets_config();
endif; // if (!function_exists('sync_widgets_config')):
```

Can you suggest a method (or plugin) which will configure my widgets for the theme, and after I change the theme, widgets will appear as saved inside the theme?

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem. I made next steps:

In both themes I registered widgets areas from both themes:

```
// Desktop areas
register_sidebar(array(
    'name' => 'Top area',
...
));
//...
// Mobile areas
register_sidebar(array(
    'name' => 'Sliding area',
...
));
```

After this, I configured widgets for my desktop theme and added widgets into mobile widget areas too.

```
// If user agent is mobile, we will change theme on fly
if (wp_is_mobile()) {
    add_filter('stylesheet', 'change_theme', 1);
    add_filter('template', 'change_theme', 1);
}

// Return mobile theme name
function change_theme($theme)
{
    return 'mobiletheme';
}
```